# Calling stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure

```
create or replace procedure get_login(p_username in varchar2)
is

begin
    select USERPASSWORD 
    from LOGIN 
    where USERNAME = p_username;

end;
```

and I try to call it in C# with this

```
public string login(string username)
{    
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("get_login",conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        OracleParameter obja = new OracleParameter("P_USERNAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
        obja.Value = username;
        obja.UdtTypeName = "varchar2";
      //  OracleParameter objb = new OracleParameter("P_USERPASSWORD", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(obja);

        Login = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); 
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }   
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return Login;
}
```

but when I run it I get this error:

> ORA-06550: Regel 1, kolom 7:
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_LOGIN'.
>   ORA-06550: Regel 1, kolom 7:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored.
>   System.Exception {Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException}

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here. It might be the procedure but testing that in the database works. I probably did something wrong and I don't know what.

Also if I may ask what does `obja.UdtTypeName` mean? I followed an example of a friend so I'm not really sure.

P.S: English is not my first language so if I got some terms wrong I'm sorry

edit:

```
public DBConnect()
{
    conn = new OracleConnection();

    String pcn = "login";
    String pw = "pass";



    conn.ConnectionString = "User Id=" + pcn + ";Password=" + pw + ";Data Source=" + "//ipofdatabase" + ";";
}
```

edit2:

```
create or replace 
procedure get_login(p_username in varchar2)
is
begin
select USERPASSWORD from LOGIN where USERNAME = p_username;
end;
```

when i do that i get this error:
Error(4,1): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Comment: are parameters case sensitive? I always ensure that I match the case I use from code to `SQL`

Answer (score 3):

You have only added 1 parameter:

```
    OracleParameter objb = new OracleParameter("P_USERPASSWORD",       OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(obja);
```

should be:

```
   OracleParameter objb = new OracleParameter("P_USERPASSWORD", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
   cmd.Parameters.Add(obja);
   objb.Size = 255;
   cmd.Parameters.Add(objb);
```

To get the value, change:

```
Login = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

To this:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Login = objb.Value.ToString();
```

Comment: thanks! i didn't see that. but maybe if you could help me with one more thing it says now that it doesn't find data(records?), but i'm 100% sure there is something in the database with the parameters i send with it.

Comment: i don't know what that is referring to.

Comment: i'm trying to get the password out of the database so that i can see if it matches with the password in the textbox where i log in. so in my database there is an account with login: test and password : test. when i send the username: test it doesnt find any data of it in the database. i get this error ORA-01403: no data found

Comment: just run this SQL and replace with the value you are sending...  does it find a row?  select USERPASSWORD 
    into v_string 
    from LOGIN 
    where USERNAME = p_username

Comment: yeah i tested that and it does find a value

Comment: when debugging DB related issues, always validate the raw SQL first and know what the procedure is returning... if the query doesn't return and data then you know where to look

Comment: ok, now execute the procedure instead of the raw SQL, make sure you are executing under the same creds as when you do at runtime.

Comment: when i run the procedure it gives me the right value back. btw i use sql developer i just clicked run on my procedure don't know if that's ok

Comment: is that how you connect to the DB (credentials) when you run the app?

Comment: don't knwo what you mean exactly but i edited a part in that's what i use to connect to the database

Comment: gotta run to meeting... i'm saying that the connection string you use when you run the application probably has an ID and PWD to connect to the DB is that the same ID/PWD you are using when you test.

Comment: ok, your problem isn't the query.  Sorry I am just now figuring out what you want..  You need to get the value from the output parameter not the return value of the ExecuteScalar()..  I will update the answer.

Comment: i'm still getting an error when i try to run it. it still says that ORA-01403: no data found

Comment: you must set the length of the parameter, output parameters must have that set.

Comment: what do you exactly mean with this i don't really understand.

Comment: look at the answer, I have modified it.  objb.Size must be set with a length.

Comment: that message means your query is not finding any data, not sure how I can help you on that.

Comment: yes i was afraid of that. but anyways thanks for all the help i appreciate it

Comment: are you able to change the procedure?  If so (just for testing) remove the output parameter and the "into" in the procedure and just have the procedure do a SELECT with a result set.  Put your original Login = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString() back and see if that has any impact.

Comment: well when i try that i get an error, please look at what i edited

Comment: i modified your answer, look at how i have the procedure, also do NOT add the objb parameter.   And use your original ExecuteScalar() code...

Comment: I'm no oracle DBA but should your parameter in the WHERE clause actually be :p_username  (note the colon)?

Comment: :p_username gives an error so i don't think the colon needs to be there